# FullScreenEvent class - overlaying elements

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

**Updated:**

I'm using BitmapImage to overlay two png files & GlowFilter to Overlay text  over an element called remoteVideoDisplay. When I click my Full Screen button (the function is below) my BitmapImage overlays are not in the bottom right hand corner in full screen mode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/36UJK.jpg

Source without my additions: https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaClients/blob/master/VideoPhone/src/VideoPhone.mxml

**Full Screen Function:**

```
        protected function fullScreenButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            videoBox.removeElement(remoteVideoDisplay);
            videoBox.removeElement(overlayBox);

            stage.addChild(remoteVideoDisplay);
            stage.addChild(overlayBox);

            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
            stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            overlayBox.width = stage.stageWidth;
            overlayBox.height = stage.stageHeight;
            overlayBox.validateDisplayList();

            remoteVideo.width = stage.stageWidth;
            remoteVideo.height = stage.stageHeight;
            remoteVideoDisplay.width = stage.stageWidth;
            remoteVideoDisplay.height = stage.stageHeight;

            stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, fullScreenHandler);                 
        }

        protected function fullScreenHandler(event:FullScreenEvent):void
        {
            if(!event.fullScreen)
            {
                stage.removeChild(remoteVideoDisplay);
                stage.removeChild(overlayBox);

                videoBox.addElement(remoteVideoDisplay);
                videoBox.addElement(overlayBox);

                overlayBox.width = 320;
                overlayBox.height = 40;

                remoteVideo.width = videoBox.width;
                remoteVideo.height = videoBox.height;
                remoteVideoDisplay.percentWidth = remoteVideoDisplay.percentHeight = 100;

                stage.removeEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, fullScreenHandler);                  
            }
        }
```

**Overlay:**

```
<s:HGroup>
    <s:Group id="videoBox" width="320" height="240">
        <s:Group id="overlayBox" width="320" height="40" depth="1">
            <mx:Label alpha=".8" color="0xffffff" 
                filters="{[new GlowFilter(0x0167bb,1,4,4,8,1)]}"
                text=" Version: 123456"/>                
            <s:BitmapImage id="runtimeimg1" right="81" bottom="2" width="23" height="24" alpha=".6" source="01.png"/>
            <s:BitmapImage id="runtimeimg2" right="56" bottom="2" width="24" height="24" alpha=".6" source="02.png"/>
        </s:Group>
        <mx:VideoDisplay id="remoteVideoDisplay" width="100%" height="100%" depth="0"/>
    </s:Group>
</s:HGroup>
```

**Button:**

```
    <s:HGroup includeIn="CallEstablished" verticalAlign="middle">
        <s:Button id="fullscreenButton" includeIn="CallEstablished" label="FULLSCREEN"
                  click="fullScreenButton_clickHandler(event)" enabled="true"/>
    </s:HGroup>
```

**Libraries (imports):**

```
        import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;

        import mx.charts.chartClasses.StackedSeries;
        import mx.collections.ArrayList;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
        import mx.formatters.DateFormatter;
        import flash.filters.GlowFilter;
        import flash.filters.BitmapFilterQuality;
        import flash.filters.BitmapFilterType;
        import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;

        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.net.navigateToURL;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
        import flash.net.URLVariables;


        // Libraries for Brightness Contrast Hue Saturation

        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import fl.motion.AdjustColor;
        import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter;
        import fl.events.SliderEvent;   
        import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes. Have the decency to comment on what's wrong with the post.

Comment: Is there a possibility to provide your flex project ?

Comment: Source without my [above] additions (overlay\button): https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaClients/blob/master/VideoPhone/src/VideoPhone.mxml it's the same thing

Comment: I know, but the problem here is with your additions (the overlay) ;)

Comment: oh I added the overlay here: https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaClients/blob/master/VideoPhone/src/VideoPhone.mxml#L1017 and the Button I just capitalized: https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaClients/blob/master/VideoPhone/src/VideoPhone.mxml#L1045 and my libaries (imports) I updated above

Comment: Did you have time to look it over?

Comment: I tried it ( without video streams ), but I didn't got the behavior that you have mentioned ! Try to isolate the part that you have added and test again... Could you provide more details, some snapshots, ... ?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/zs6vb (red blocks = omitted for privacy) image1: the logotype and version is displayed fine in non-full screen mode, image 2: full screen: the logotype and version are missing, image3: after escaping full screen the logotype and version are missing. This has to do with setting\unsetting the stage. "Try to isolate the part that you have added and test again" This doesn't make any sense if I remove the logotype\version then of course it won't vanish because it's no longer in the code.

Comment: Someone else told me "what you want to do is to find the flash.media.Video instance and add that to the stage" maybe that helps

Comment: the component would be the mx:VideoDisplay element
 or rather, the code that said element corresponds to
 which is the mx.controls.VideoDisplay class

Comment: By "isolate", I meant that you put just a simple video player with your overlays and do a test. I see you snapshots, I think that the video player is covering your overlays, try to resize it on fullscreen mode ( put it as 480x360 for example not the whole screen ).

Comment: set  remoteVideo.width = 486;
    remoteVideo.height = 360; right?

Comment: And the `remoteVideoDisplay` also, yes ..

Comment: http://imgur.com/2dzTHxv (full screen mode) now I see the logo below it and the Version is nowhere to be found (im guessing its above the VideoDisplay Element)

Comment: That's it ! you have now to play with depths of your objects to get your overlays visible on the fullscreen mode.

Comment: Are you sure it's the depths? Isn't it pushing them above\below? Can you post an example of how to resolve this issue so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think that the simplest method is to use a `Group` to put your overlays, then add and remove it from the stage as your video object :

```
<s:HGroup>
    <s:Group id="videoBox" width="320" height="240">
        <s:Group id="overlayBox" width="320" height="40" depth="1">
            <mx:Label alpha=".8" color="0xffffff" 
                filters="{[new GlowFilter(0x0167bb,1,4,4,8,1)]}"
                text=" Version: 123456"/>                
            <s:BitmapImage id="runtimeimg1" right="81" bottom="2" width="23" height="24" alpha=".6" source="01.png"/>
            <s:BitmapImage id="runtimeimg2" right="56" bottom="2" width="24" height="24" alpha=".6" source="02.png"/>
        </s:Group>
        <mx:VideoDisplay id="remoteVideoDisplay" width="100%" height="100%" depth="0"/>
    </s:Group>
</s:HGroup>
```

Then

```
protected function fullScreenButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    videoBox.removeElement(remoteVideoDisplay);
    videoBox.removeElement(overlayBox);

    stage.addChild(remoteVideoDisplay);
    stage.addChild(overlayBox);

    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
    stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

    remoteVideo.width = stage.stageWidth;
    remoteVideo.height = stage.stageHeight;
    remoteVideoDisplay.width = stage.stageWidth;
    remoteVideoDisplay.height = stage.stageHeight;

    stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, fullScreenHandler);                 
}

protected function fullScreenHandler(event:FullScreenEvent):void
{
    if(!event.fullScreen)
    {
        stage.removeChild(remoteVideoDisplay);
        stage.removeChild(overlayBox);

        videoBox.addElement(remoteVideoDisplay);
        videoBox.addElement(overlayBox);

        remoteVideo.width = videoBox.width;
        remoteVideo.height = videoBox.height;
        remoteVideoDisplay.percentWidth = remoteVideoDisplay.percentHeight = 100;

        stage.removeEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, fullScreenHandler);                  
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

To avoid the spark `Group` resizing problem, you can use [`validateDisplayList()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#validateDisplayList())

> Validates the position and size of children and draws other visuals ...

So in your case you can do :

```
protected function fullScreenButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    videoBox.removeElement(remoteVideoDisplay);
    videoBox.removeElement(overlayBox);

    stage.addChild(remoteVideoDisplay);
    stage.addChild(overlayBox);

    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
    stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

    overlayBox.width = stage.stageWidth;
    overlayBox.height = stage.stageHeight;
    overlayBox.validateDisplayList();

    remoteVideo.width = stage.stageWidth;
    remoteVideo.height = stage.stageHeight;
    remoteVideoDisplay.width = stage.stageWidth;
    remoteVideoDisplay.height = stage.stageHeight;

    stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, fullScreenHandler);                 
}

protected function fullScreenHandler(event:FullScreenEvent):void
{
    if(!event.fullScreen)
    {
        stage.removeChild(remoteVideoDisplay);
        stage.removeChild(overlayBox);

        videoBox.addElement(remoteVideoDisplay);
        videoBox.addElement(overlayBox);

        overlayBox.width = 320;
        overlayBox.height = 40;

        remoteVideo.width = videoBox.width;
        remoteVideo.height = videoBox.height;
        remoteVideoDisplay.percentWidth = remoteVideoDisplay.percentHeight = 100;

        stage.removeEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, fullScreenHandler);                  
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: I'll accept the answer + award the bounty when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: Hey I changed bottom to -199 (to fix the logo in windowed mode) since the bitmapimage is positioned differently now. Here are the results: http://imgur.com/a/1QZXa for some reason in full screen mode the logotype is not positioned in the bottom right hand corner. Everything else is perfect. Thanks for all the hard work so far. I accepted the bounty in the mean time and will accept the answer once we figure this out. Thank you! :P

Comment: I still can't figure out how to position it in the bottom right hand corner in full screen mode. If anyone else knows feel free to post.

Comment: Can you update your example? Sorry. I'm struggling with this. I think you mean   overlaybox.width = stage.stageWidth;
    overlaybox.height = stage.stageHeight;
    overlaybox.width = stage.stageWidth;
    overlaybox.height = stage.stageHeight;

Comment: @michelle Yes, try it and don't forget to resize it again to its first dimensions after exiting fullscreen mode. Sorry, I don't have FB now to test it.

Comment: @michelle And what did you got ( description or snapshot ) ?

Comment: It looks exactly the same as before.          I used       overlayBox.width = stage.stageWidth;
            overlayBox.height = stage.stageHeight; to set the stage Full Screen and      overlayBox.width = 320;
     overlayBox.height = 40; to set it Window Mode

Comment: I also tried     overlayBox.width = remoteVideoDisplay.width;
    overlayBox.height = remoteVideoDisplay.height;

Comment: if you have any idea on how to fix this just let me know thanks

Comment: @michelle To avoid the problem, you can do `overlayBox.validateDisplayList();` after resizing the `Group`.

Comment: I updated my full screen function to match what you suggested. See the code above. In fullscreen now I see text=" Version: 123456 but the two bitmapimages are no longer visible in FullScreen. Maybe update your example if my placement is incorrect?

Comment: @michelle I have the same code, but it's working fine for me. Take a look [here](http://imgur.com/76Pk3au).

Comment: Does where I place overlayBox.width = stage.stageWidth;
overlayBox.height = stage.stageHeight;
overlayBox.validateDisplayList(); matter? Should it be after  remoteVideo.width = stage.stageWidth;
    remoteVideo.height = stage.stageHeight;
    remoteVideoDisplay.width = stage.stageWidth;
    remoteVideoDisplay.height = stage.stageHeight;? Maybe update your example.

Comment: Maybe update your example with all the final changes. Sorry.

Comment: @michelle I put my used code, it's the same as yours.

Comment: Alright so here's the problem. In window mode bottom has to be "-198" or the placement will not be in the bottom right hand corner of VideoDisplay and in Full Screen bottom has to be bottom="2" or it won't be visible.

Comment: @michelle But for that you can simply change the size of `overlayBox ` to (320x240) and set always the bottom to 2 !